# Can't connect to SSH using Kerberos in Mac OS 10.12

Tags: linux, ssh, kerberos

My mac is joined to my AD and i'd like to connect my Linux servers using SSH kerberos auth.

It doesn't work and gives me that error :

```
ssh -k -v alex@jeedom
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/alex/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to jeedom [192.168.1.11] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/alex/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/alex/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/alex/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/alex/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/alex/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/alex/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/alex/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/alex/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to jeedom:22 as 'alex'
debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
Server (host/jeedom.home.lan@HOME.LAN) unknown while looking up 'host/jeedom.home.lan@HOME.LAN' (cached result, timeout in 1060 sec)

debug1:  An invalid name was supplied
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 2 752 43 14 2

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 6 1 5 5 14

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
unknown mech-code 2 for mech 1 3 6 1 4 1 311 2 2 10

debug1:  An unsupported mechanism was requested
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 5 1 5 2 7

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 6 1 5 2 5

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ooO8JUvIitiNg3tm1nUGs2uPLJYPeY2u21u2BLNi6n8
debug1: Host 'jeedom' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/alex/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/alex/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/alex/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/alex/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/alex/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

sshd_config :

```
# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
KerberosAuthentication no
KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication no
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no
```

.ssh/config

```
User alex@HOME.LAN
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIKeyExchange yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
SendEnv LANG LC_*
GSSAPITrustDNS yes
```

I'm stuck and can't figure out what's going wrong. DNS are ok... Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated !!

Thanx !

Comment: “KerberosAuthentication no” - So why did you disable it?  You specified the “user@Ad”@machine right?

Comment: My bad, i enabled KerberosAuthentication but getting same error after that... What do you mean by specifying user@Ad@machine ?

Comment: @Ramhound Because `KerberosAuthentication` doesn't actually use Kerberos the regular way. All it does is verify the password against a KDC _server-side_ (similar to pam_krb5) rather than requiring the client to send a ticket. It is useless in this case.

Comment: @jaydee99 If you are using Kerberos to authenticate an Active Directory domain username to log into a Linux client which trusts the AD because of Kerberos, then your username to that machine, should your “username@AD”@Machine

Comment: @Ramhound yes, i specified User alex@HOME.LAN in .ssh/config and even tried manually, but still have same log...

Comment: I've noticed that libpam-krb5 is not installed... Do i have to install this package and if yes, how to enable it ?

Comment: what is the output of klist -kt on the server a klist on the mac?